# Why doesn't the POD use the requested cpu/memory limit in K8S?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have deployed a pod with cpu/memory limit on the spec:

```
resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 1
              memory: 4Gi
```

but the limit looks different from `kubectl describe pod` command:

```
Init Containers:
  elastic-internal-init-filesystem:
    Container ID:  docker://174be47d381c76b64ba406d1e1a80c685fca407a926074df32d8dd5689f359f2
    Image:         docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.15.2
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch@sha256:a1dce08d504b22e87adc849c94dcae53f6a0bd12648a4d99d7f9fc07bb2e8a3e
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      bash
      -c
      /mnt/elastic-internal/scripts/prepare-fs.sh
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Wed, 31 May 2023 10:42:34 +1000
      Finished:     Wed, 31 May 2023 10:42:36 +1000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     100m
      memory:  50Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:     100m
      memory:  50Mi
```

The `describe` command returns 100m cpu and 50Mi memory. However I requested 4G memory and 1 cpu. Why doesn't it use the limit from the spec file?

The full spec file is:

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: elk
spec:
  version: 7.15.2
  serviceAccountName: docker-sa
  http:
    tls:
      selfSignedCertificate:
        disabled: true
  nodeSets:
  - name: node
    count: 2
    config:
      network.host: 0.0.0.0
      xpack.security.enabled: false
      # xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: false
      # xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: false
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        initContainers:
        - name: sysctl
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
          command: ['sh', '-c', 'sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144']
        containers:
        - name: elasticsearch
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
              - bash
              - -c
              - /mnt/elastic-internal/scripts/readiness-probe-script.sh
            failureThreshold: 3
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 12
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 12
          env:
          - name: READINESS_PROBE_TIMEOUT
            value: "120"
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 1
              memory: 4Gi
          volumeMounts:
          - name: elasticsearch-data
            mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: elasticsearch-data
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        storageClassName: ebs-sc
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 512Gi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
...
podTemplate:
  spec:
    initContainers:
    - name: sysctl
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
      command: ['sh', '-c', 'sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144']
      resources:  # <-- Specify resources per-container
        limits:   # <-- Set the limit
          cpu: 1
          memory: 4Gi    
        requests:
          cpu: 1
          memory: 4Gi
        ...
```

Comment: But why? The init container seems to have completed quite happily without the large request.

Comment: Read the question carefully; which container does the statement `The describe command returns 100m cpu and 50Mi memory....` referred to. It's clearly reflected in the describe output.

Comment: Yes, I can read.  But the answer should not be "add unnecessary resources to the init container" but rather "look at the output for the container (named elasticsearch) for which you requested those resources".

Comment: oh, yes. you are right, I was looking at a wrong container. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Resources are per container, not per pod.  Your spec has 2 containers, with resource request only for the second (non-init) container.

Your 'describe' output only shows the init container. Though actually, it doesn't seem to be the init container named in your spec.

Answer (score 1):

Resources are managed individually for each container. To specify resource for  Init Container, You need to provide resource under the init container.

Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/

Here is the updated configuration file:
I have added the resources under the Init Container.

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: elk
spec:
  version: 7.15.2
  serviceAccountName: docker-sa
  http:
    tls:
      selfSignedCertificate:
        disabled: true
  nodeSets:
  - name: node
    count: 2
    config:
      network.host: 0.0.0.0
      xpack.security.enabled: false
      # xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: false
      # xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: false
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        initContainers:
        - name: sysctl
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
          command: ['sh', '-c', 'sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144']
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 1
              memory: 4Gi
        containers:
        - name: elasticsearch
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
              - bash
              - -c
              - /mnt/elastic-internal/scripts/readiness-probe-script.sh
            failureThreshold: 3
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 12
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 12
          env:
          - name: READINESS_PROBE_TIMEOUT
            value: "120"
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 1
              memory: 4Gi
          volumeMounts:
          - name: elasticsearch-data
            mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: elasticsearch-data
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        storageClassName: ebs-sc
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 512Gi
```